# conducting GAM-GEE in gamm4 R package?

Tags: r, statistics, spatial, gam

I am trying to analyze some visual transect data of organisms to generate a habitat distribution model. Once organisms are sighted, they are followed as point data is collected at a given time interval.  Because of the autocorrelation among these "follows," I wish to utilize a GAM-GEE approach similar to that of Pirotta et al. 2011, using packages 'yags' and 'splines' (http://www.int-res.com/abstracts/meps/v436/p257-272/).  Their R scripts are shown here (http://www.int-res.com/articles/suppl/m436p257_supp/m436p257_supp1-code.r). I have used this code with limited success and multiple issues of models failing to converge.

Below is the structure of my data:

```
> str(dat2)

'data.frame':   10792 obs. of  4 variables:

 $ dist_slag       : num  26475 26340 25886 25400 24934 ...
 $ Depth           : num  -10.1 -10.5 -16.6 -22.2 -29.7 ...
$ dolphin_presence: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...


 $ block           : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...


> head(dat2)

  dist_slag    Depth dolphin_presence block
1  26475.47 -10.0934                0     1
2  26340.47 -10.4870                0     1
3  25886.33 -16.5752                0     1
4  25399.88 -22.2474                0     1



5  24934.29 -29.6797                0     1
6  24519.90 -26.2370                0     1
```

Here is the summary of my block variable (indicating the number of groups for which autocorrelation exists within each block

```
> summary(dat2$block)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   1.00   39.00   76.00   73.52  111.00  148.00
```

However, I would like to use the package 'gamm4', as I am more familiar with Professor Simon Wood's packages and functions, and it appears gamm4 might be the most appropriate. It is important to note that the models have a binary response (organism presence of absence along a transect), and thus why I think gamm4 is more appropriate than gamm.  In the gamm help, it provides the following example for autocorrelation within factors:

```
## more complicated autocorrelation example - AR errors
## only within groups defined by `fac'
e <- rnorm(n,0,sig)
for (i in 2:n) e[i] <- 0.6*e[i-1]*(fac[i-1]==fac[i]) + e[i]
y <- f + e
b <- gamm(y~s(x,k=20),correlation=corAR1(form=~1|fac))
```

Following this example, the following is the code I used for my dataset

```
b <- gamm4(dolphin_presence~s(dist_slag)+s(Depth),random=(form=~1|block),  family=binomial(),data=dat)
```

However, by examining the output (summary(b$gam)) and specifically summary(b$mer)), I am either unsure of how to interpret the results, or do not believe that the autocorrelation within the group is being taken into consideration.

```
> summary(b$gam)

Family: binomial 
Link function: logit 

Formula:
dolphin_presence ~ s(dist_slag) + s(Depth)

Parametric coefficients:


            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
    (Intercept)  -13.968      5.145  -2.715  0.00663 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Approximate significance of smooth terms:


               edf Ref.df Chi.sq  p-value    
s(dist_slag) 4.943  4.943  70.67 6.85e-14 ***
s(Depth)     6.869  6.869 115.59  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 



R-sq.(adj) =  0.317glmer.ML score =  10504  Scale est. = 1         n = 10792
> 

> summary(b$mer)
Generalized linear mixed model fit by the Laplace approximation 


   AIC   BIC logLik deviance
 10514 10551  -5252    10504
Random effects:
 Groups Name         Variance Std.Dev.
 Xr     s(dist_slag) 1611344  1269.39 
 Xr.0   s(Depth)       98622   314.04 
Number of obs: 10792, groups: Xr, 8; Xr.0, 8



Fixed effects:
                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
X(Intercept)      -13.968      5.145  -2.715  0.00663 **
Xs(dist_slag)Fx1  -35.871     33.944  -1.057  0.29063   
Xs(Depth)Fx1        3.971      3.740   1.062  0.28823   


---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            X(Int) X(_)F1
Xs(dst_s)F1  0.654       
Xs(Dpth)Fx1 -0.030  0.000
>
```

How do I ensure that autocorrelation is indeed being accounted for within each unique value of the "block" variable? What is the simplest way to interpret the output for "summary(b$mer)"?

The results do differ from a normal gam (package mgcv) using the same variables and parameters without the "correlation=..." term, indicating that something different is occurring.

However, when I use a different variable for the correlation term (season), I get the SAME output:

```
> dat2 <- data.frame(dist_slag = dat$dist_slag, Depth = dat$Depth, dolphin_presence = dat$dolphin_presence,

+ block = dat$block, season=dat$season)
 > head(dat2)
      dist_slag    Depth dolphin_presence block season
1  26475.47 -10.0934                0     1      F
2  26340.47 -10.4870                0     1      F

3  25886.33 -16.5752                0     1      F
4  25399.88 -22.2474                0     1      F
5  24934.29 -29.6797                0     1      F
6  24519.90 -26.2370                0     1      F

> summary(dat2$season)

   F    S 
3224 7568 


> b <- gamm4(dolphin_presence~s(dist_slag)+s(Depth),correlation=corAR1(1, form=~1 |   season), family=binomial(),data=dat2)
> summary(b$gam)

Family: binomial 
Link function: logit 


Formula:
dolphin_presence ~ s(dist_slag) + s(Depth)

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
    (Intercept)  -13.968      5.145  -2.715  0.00663 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 


Approximate significance of smooth terms:
               edf Ref.df Chi.sq  p-value    
s(dist_slag) 4.943  4.943  70.67 6.85e-14 ***
s(Depth)     6.869  6.869 115.59  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 


R-sq.(adj) =  0.317glmer.ML score =  10504  Scale est. = 1         n = 10792
> summary(b$mer)
Generalized linear mixed model fit by the Laplace approximation 
   AIC   BIC logLik deviance

 10514 10551  -5252    10504
Random effects:
 Groups Name         Variance Std.Dev.
 Xr     s(dist_slag) 1611344  1269.39 
 Xr.0   s(Depth)       98622   314.04 
Number of obs: 10792, groups: Xr, 8; Xr.0, 8


Fixed effects:
                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
X(Intercept)      -13.968      5.145  -2.715  0.00663 **
Xs(dist_slag)Fx1  -35.871     33.944  -1.057  0.29063   
Xs(Depth)Fx1        3.971      3.740   1.062  0.28823   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            X(Int) X(_)F1
Xs(dst_s)F1  0.654       
Xs(Dpth)Fx1 -0.030  0.000
>
```

I just want to make sure it is correctly allowing for correlation within each value for the "block" variable. How do I formulate the model to say that autocorrelation can exist within each single value for block, but assume independence among blocks?

On another note, I am also receiving the following warning message after model completion for larger models (with many more variables than 2):

```
Warning message:
 In mer_finalize(ans) : false convergence (8)
```

Answer (score 5):

- `gamm4` is built on top of `lme4`, which does **not** allow for a `correlation` parameter (in contrast to the `nlme`, package, which underlies `mgcv::gamm`).  `mgcv::gamm` *does* handle binary data, although it uses PQL, which is generally less accurate than Laplace/GHQ approximations as in `gamm4/lme4`. It is unfortunate (!!) that you're not getting a warning telling you that the `correlation` argument is being ignored (when I try a simple example using a `correlation` argument with `lme4`, I do get a warning, but it's possible that the extra argument is getting swallowed somewhere inside `gamm4`).
- Your desired autocorrelation structure ("autocorrelation can exist within each single value for block, but assume independence among blocks") is exactly the way correlation structures are coded in `nlme` (and hence in `mgcv::gamm`).
- I would use `mcgv::gamm`, and would suggest that if at all possible you try it out on some simulated data with known structure (or use the data set provided in the supplementary material above and see if you can reproduce their qualitative conclusions with your alternative approach).
- StackOverflow is nice, but there is probably more mixed model expertise at `r-sig-mixed-models@r-project.org`

Comment: Professor Bolker- thank you for your quick and thorough response! I enjoyed your text on Ecological models in R....      I will attempt to use mgcv:gamm on both my data as well as the that of Pirotta et al.  I am assuming the correlation structure part of the formula would be the same as I attempted in gamm4? ie "correlation=corAR1(1, form=~1 | block)"   Thank you again!

Comment: I think that's the right correlation specification (corAR1(form=~1|block) might be sufficient)

Comment: Unfortunately, as I run the following code, I obtain the subsequent errors.                                                            > fit1 <- gamm(dolphin_presence~s(Depth, k=4)+s(dist_slag, k=4),correlation=corAR1(form=~1 | block), family=binomial(),data=dat)

 Maximum number of PQL iterations:  20 
iteration 1
iteration 2
iteration 3
iteration 4
iteration 5
Error in `coef<-.corAR1`(`*tmp*`, value = value[parMap[, i]]) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)                        Any ideas as to why this occurs? I also get an error of "convergence error code = 1" with more vars.

Comment: Not sure.  These are complex models, you may have to "divide and conquer" by trying various simpler subsets.  Have you tried it out on Pirotta et al's sample data? (Have you removed NAs from your data and examined the data graphically for wonky features?)